# How to get query string in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there anyway how can I get query string in Polymer?

```
http://localhost:8080/search?param=ppshein
```

I want to get `search?param=ppshein` or `param=ppshein` in Polymer.

I've tried to get query string in `app-route` but it display nothing.

```
<app-route
    route="[[route]]"
    pattern="/:id"
    data="{{routeData}}"></app-route>

[[routeData.id]] **
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`<app-location>.queryParams`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-route/app-location#property-queryParams):

```
<app-location route="{{route}}" query-params="{{queryParams}}"></app-location>
```

`queryParams` is an object containing key/value pairs of the parsed query parameters. Given `http://localhost:8080/search?param=ppshein`, `queryParams` would be:

```
{
  param: 'ppshein'
}
```